# File Age Reporting

Tags: powershell, fileserver

I often find my answers on this site without, but on this occasion I need more personalized assistance. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have been messing around with trying to draw a report off my NAS system to get statistics of the Age of Data and the Size of data so I can attempt to provide a Charge Back/Show back solution.

I have managed to do this mostly with Powershell using get-childitem and I have even trying to tap into .net using [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories, 
and other commands. All these solutions work, but I seem to get really slow times getting this information, especially if I compare this to Jam TreeSize which fishes this information out fairly quickly.

to note, I have even tried multi-threading in powershell, thinking if I can collect the data from various points it would collect the whole data would be quicker, but I have had largely mix results.

I'm hoping someone else has tackled this sort of project before and managed to get a nice quick(er) way of doing this. I am even open to other languages tackling this.

Quick notes, I am doing this in powershell v5. I have also started learning a bit of python so if anyone has suggestion in that it would be a great place for me to learn.

Edit:

OK Here are some examples. 
Times: 
Treesize takes 10 seconds 
Powershell Get-ChildItem takes about 2minutes 
Powershell dotnet actions takes about 2 minutes

Number of objects counted 60 000 objects, size 120gb.

get-childitem with recurse will get you all file objects in a specified location including their attributes, such as last accessed time and size in bytes dotnet you need to use a combination of EnumerateFiles etc and then loop that with FileInfo which is get the file objects in the given location and then inspect their attributes respectively

In terms of multithreading I will point you to some links which I used, it will be too much to add in here, but I have tried creating a runspacepool, but I also tried manually running two separate runspaces to compare results and they were much the same. why I am obsessed with times, while the test directory I am using above is only 2 minutes, my NAS in some volumes has millions of files. The one test I did took an hour and a half to complete, and if I were to do that with other volumes it would take hours. I just want to find speeds closer to Treesize

**Edit:** I have marked robocopy workaround as the answer, however if you do have any suggestions on a different language and procedure please feel free to comment and it will be something I will look into in the future

Comment: Can you post the code you've used, what sort of time are they taking, what info are you trying to get?

Comment: While the topic might be interesting, the question is too broad.

Comment: Comments are not meant for extending information which belongs in your question first hand. Please edit your question so follow up readers don't need to readd through all this. (I didn't and I don't intend to)

Comment: Thanks LotPings, first time poster, will learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been there, and to get what you want is... tricky, at least: TreeSize is reading the information directly from the MFT table, while `Get-ChildItem` is acting at a higher level, already in the OS. Therefore, the speed varies a lot.

So if you want to speed up your report you really need to go under the hood and code something at lower levels.

For me, even if it wasn't the fastest solution, I got a compromise and used `robocopy /l /log:c:\mylog.txt` (which doesn't copy a byte, and just logs the files to `mylog.txt`), and then I've parsed it. You can play with the multithreading option (`/MT:[N]`, where N is 8 by default) to speed it up.

What I find useful with this method is that, if I need further investigation, I've all the data I need in a file and therefore it'll be faster to query it. Static, not updated, but when you're talking about million of files, a photo of a certain moment is a good approach, I think.

Comment: Thanks curropar, I am going to give this a bash tomorrow and see how I come with it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: TreeSize uses MFT only when started as admin and only when scanning an complete local drive. MFT is faster especially on old HDD, the increase in speed on SSDs is negligible. TreeSize Professional offers command line options that many customer use to e.g. generate a file age statistics. Full disclosure: I am the author of TreeSize, let us know if a feature is missing that is needed for your reports.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @JoachimMarder! I work as a sysadmin, and I normally start it with admin rights, and against the root of the volume, normally to find why the volume is almost full, so that explains my experience. About going Professional, well, that's not my decision, sadly.

Comment: @JoachimMarder Well as you can see I find your application frustratingly efficient, hahaha. Well your application scans network shares pretty well too. If your willing and out of personal interest does Treesize cache local searches at all? I sometimes get the feeling that if I re-scan a directory it was a bit faster than before. If that's secret sauce, don't worry sharing :)

I will definitely also be looking into those command lines  you are talking about. Is it Powershell or cmd?

Comment: @StuartW: TreeSize does not cache, but Windows does, which is why a re-scan is typically faster. Command line is cmd, see: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/online_manual/EN/command_line_opt.html

Comment: @curropar: We often have customers that end up in buying Treesize or SpaceObServer after working several weeks on their PowerShell scripts. Even though our products do cost money it should be easy to see for your boss what is cheaper.

Comment: @StuartW: SpaceObServer has an OLE Automation interface that can alos be used in PowerShell: http://www.jam-software.com/spaceobserver/ole_automation.shtml